# How to execute cmd command from text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

As title says, I need to execute cmd command from text file.Let's say I have text file called `file` and in it it's written `Color A`.I need something like command: `type file.txt` and not just write it on screen, but I want it to press enter meanwhile.Batch file options are welcomed too.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use save your normal file with batch programming in it with `.bat` extension. And run that file `WhateverNameItIs.bat` on your command prompt.

Saved it as `file.bat`

```
 @ECHO ON
 ECHO Color A
```

In your case you can drag file from your where your are to command prompt. Or Using `CD` you can reach out where your file is saved within your command prompt. Fire up `file.bat` on your command prompt will execute whatever batch programming is written on that file.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
xcopy Name.txt (your Folder)
ren Name.txt Name.bat
call Name.bat (or full location of Name.bat)
```

it should work